# Query: Where hidden = '0'

Tags: mysql

How can I make my search form to only list results where `hidden = '0';` + rest of the options ?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT *
FROM        users u
LEFT JOIN   menues m
ON          u.user_id = m.restaurant_id
WHERE       (restaurant LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%'))
OR          city LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')
");
$stmt->bindParam(":term", $term);
$stmt->execute();
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What was wrong with adding `AND hidden = '0';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I hope I understand what you need:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT *
FROM        users u
LEFT JOIN   menues m
ON          u.user_id = m.restaurant_id
WHERE       (((restaurant LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%'))
OR          city LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%'))
AND         hidden = 0)
");
$stmt->bindParam(":term", $term);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just add

```
AND hidden = '0'
```

to the end of your `WHERE` clause so your query ends

```
.
.
.
WHERE (restaurant LIKE ...
OR city LIKE ...)
AND hidden='0'
```

Incidentally is `hidden` really a character-based column? If not, you should be adding `hidden=0` (without single quotes)